# PCI process, how to solve mambo vulnerability CVE 2006-0871 on debian 8?

Tags: pci-dss, pci-scope

I am involved in the process of becoming pci-dss compliant. I am really close to get it although I am having this vulnerability on the server when I am doing an external scan.
Does someone know how to solve it?

Comment: Did you check the new release as this is proposed as solution: http://mamboxchange.com/frs/?group_id=5

Comment: Which level of PCI-DSS compliance are you assessing for?

Comment: The most basic, level 4